# Functions - TQL passing function with parameters

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to create a simple function that will do a count on a table. I want to pass the table name in form of a parameter to the variable and this function will return the count as an int. Please see my function below and help me understand why this is not working.

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_rows     

(@tablename varchar(100)

RETURNS int AS

BEGIN

DECLARE     @emp_count AS int

declare     @declaration varchar(100)

@declaration='SELECT count(*) 

FROM ' + @tablename

@emp_count=cast(@declaration as int)



RETURN @emp_count

END

GO
```

The errors I am getting are as follows:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure count_rows, Line 3 Incorrect
>   syntax near 'RETURNS'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   count_rows, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near '@declaration'. Msg 178,
>   Level 15, State 1, Procedure count_rows, Line 14 A RETURN statement
>   with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Comment: You have a syntax error on nearly every second line. . Parenthesis are unbalanced, declarations and assignmnents are confused. Study the syntax carefully, and fix these errors. Use block-indenting and intellisense to get the syntax errors cleaned up, and then someone here will likely help you get the logic errors corrected.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use Dynamic SQL to handle table name that is pass in from application. For dynamic sql, function is out of the question. You will need to use stored procedure to do that.